# How to get timezone offset as ±hh:mm in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, moment-timezone

I can get the Timezone offset with the following command as:

`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` -> -330 and using moment

`moment().utcOffset()` as 330.

However, how do I get the format as ±hh:mm?

Comment: the final time should be something like `hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm`

Comment: What did you mean by that?can you show an expected format with times?

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm. This is the full picture

Comment: date and time format. e.g - `2019-01-01 12:32:45-08:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer `moment.js` you can use `.format` for formatting date or time.

```js
 const date = new Date();
let utc = moment(date).utcOffset()
console.log(moment(date).utcOffset(utc).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z"))

//and for `+00:00` it will be : 
console.log('for GMT +0000 : '+ moment(date).tz('Africa/Monrovia').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Reference : [Display](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: why in `utcOffset(330)` the argument is taken as 330. I want to make it generic

Comment: This doesn't provide in hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm format

Comment: You can store `moment(date).utcOffset()` in a variable and use it ?

Comment: `moment.utc(timestamp).utcOffset(moment(timestamp).utcOffset()).format("HH:MM:SSZ")` the command will look something this way for time

Comment: my conversionDateTime value must be in this format itself. `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+|-hh:mm`

Comment: e.g - `2019-01-01 12:32:45-08:00`

Comment: How to handle edge case where the time is in "Monrovia - Liberia" -> `Tue Sep 20 2022 03:20:04 GMT+0000` and with the above command it returns `2022-09-20 03:20:04Z` which is not in the correct format. expected is `2022-01-01 10:42:45+00:00` (can give + or - does not matter) this is google's conversion format

Comment: @Akash You can set the format for that. Try my updated answer. I think this is what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of QT Ray is a good point to start and helped me to solve the issue but actually has quite a few issues like trying to overwrite a numeric variable with a string or adding the minus in front of the string when the offset is positive.

Here is my working solution:

```
getTimezoneOffset(offset) {
  const offsetHours = Math.floor(Math.abs(offset / 60));
  const offsetMins = Math.abs(offset % 60);
  return (offset < 0 ? '-' : '+') + (offsetHours < 10 ? '0' : '') + offsetHours + ':' + (offsetMins < 10 ? '0' : '') + offsetMins;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it without a third-party library or manually converting the value with functionality.

You can do something like:

```
const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
let offsetHours = parseInt(Math.abs(offset/60));
let offsetMins = Math.abs(offset%60);
let formattedOffset;

if (offsetHours < 10) offSetHours = '0' + offsetHours;
if (offsetMins < 10) offsetMins = '0' + offsetMins;

if (offset < 0) {
  formattedOffset = '+' + offsetHours + ':' + offsetMins;
} else if (offset > 0) {
  formattedOffset = '-' + offsetHours + ':' + offsetMins;
} else if (offset === 0) {
 formattedOffset = 'Z';
}
```

That should get you pretty close.

Comment: parseInt will throw an error because it's numeric already, setting the offsetHours will do as well because you try to overwrite a number with a string, once it's offSetHours with a uppercase 'S' and I am pretty sure that the offset < 0 needs the minus upfront because that's when the offset is negative.